# a middleware to be run during every HTTP request to application except one in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I want to create my app ( I dont want to use laravel default login system)

I want to use  a middleware to be run during every HTTP request in my application except one

in laravel 5.1 documention syas I can use  **Global Middleware** but I want to not use middleware for just login page.
what should I do ?
this is my middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if( !  session()->has('Login' )  )
        {
            return redirect('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your `routes.php` page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use routes group and assign your middleware to it:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'Admin'], function () {
    // All of your routes goes here
});

// Special routes which you dont want going thorugh the this middleware goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything to your middleware. you have the free to take that route outside the route group. so it becomes a standalone route. Or you can create a new route group and put only that one route in without that middleware. eg.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
    Route::post('login','AuthenticationController');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::resource('deparments','AuthenticationController');
    Route::resource("permission_roles","PermissionRolesController");
});
```

with this the middleware affect only the second route group

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to tackle this, one is to address this in your middleware and exclude the route there, and two is to group all the routes you want to have covered by the middleware in your `routes.php` and then have the ones you want excluded outside of the grouping.

**Tackling this in middleware**

Just amend the `handle` function to include an `if` statement checking the URI requested

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->is("route/you/want/to/exclude"))
    {
        return $next($request);
    } 

    if( !  session()->has('Login' )  )
    {
        return redirect('login');
    }

   else
   {
            return redirect('login');
   }
}
```

This method allows you to set the middleware up as global middleware and you can make multiple exclusions by extending the if statement with `or $request->is()`.

**Tackling this in routes**

```
//Place all the routes you don't want protected here

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    //Place all the routes you want protected in here
});
```